# AMPScript - Create and Store couple of records to access them in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have some AMPScript writing records to a data extension. Using AMPScript I would like to store those records in a variable to access them in a javaScript function.

What is the best way to do it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
%%[
VAR @sid, @skey, @jid, @listid, @batchid, @reason, @FieldList, @Rows, @i, @Row, @Name, @Value, @BackIn, @Subscriber, @Status
SET @sid = SubscriberID
SET @skey = _SubscriberKey
SET @jid = JobID
SET @listid = ListID
SET @batchid = _JobSubscriberBatchID
SET @reason = "Landing Page Unsubscribe"
SET @email = emailaddr                                      


SET @FieldList = BuildRowsetFromString(RequestParameter("FieldList"),",")
SET @Rows = Subtract(Rowcount(@FieldList),1)
SET @BackIn="false"

for @i = 1 to @Rows do
     Set @Row = Row(@FieldList, @i)
     Set @Name = Field(@Row,1)
     Set @Value = RequestParameter(@Name)

     if @Value=="true" then 
      Set @Value="true"   
      Set @BackIn = "true" 
     else
      Set @Value="false" 
     endif

     InsertData('ENT.TEST_PrefChanges1','MemberID',@skey,'ProgramID',@Name,'Subscribed',@Value,'Modified',DateParse(NOW(),1))

next @i                                                                   

if @BackIn=="true" then
  SET @Subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty( @Subscriber, "SubscriberKey",@skey)
  SetObjectProperty( @Subscriber, "Status", "Active" )
  SET @Status = InvokeUpdate(@Subscriber)
  %%=v(@Status)=%%
endif
]%% 

<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core", "1");

var records = [];

function(){}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the `Variable.GetValue()` function.  Something like this:

```
<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

  var BackIn = Variable.GetValue("@BackIn");
  Write("<br>BackIn: " + BackIn);

</script>
```

**Reference**: [Using Server-Side JavaScript with AMPscript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/using_server_side_javascript_with_ampscript/)

Comment: Thanks @adam. I want to know how to write those records into an array after writing them to the dataExtension in AMPScript

Comment: Maybe I could use BuildRowsetFromString

Comment: It'd be easier to write the whole thing in SSJS.  Here's the boilerplate that I use: https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8